# How to use one print statement to output multiple lines of text

Tags: c, printing

this is not a problem I was just wondering if I could use fewer print statements for this problem.

```
#include <stdio.h> // for print statments
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

  int thisNumber;
  printf("%s", "Hey you! input your Number here: " );

  scanf("%d", &thisNumber );

  printf( "%s","Your number is: " );
  printf("%d\n", thisNumber );
  return 0;
}
```

I have tried this:

```
#include <stdio.h> // for print statments
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int thisNumber;
  printf("%s", "Hey you! input your Number here: " );

  scanf("%d", &thisNumber );

  printf( "Your number is: %d", thisNumber );

  return 0;
}
```

And the output was:

```
> Hey Bekhruz! input your Number here: <my input say:125>
> Your number is: 125%
```

and for some reason, I have a % sign at the end with this code. Why is it occurring and how can i solve it? Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't explain the % sign, but you did have `printf("%d\n", thisNumber );` which has the new line character `\n` at the end - you haven't included that in the condensed version

Comment: yap! it worked and actually solved my % sign problem. thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's your shell prompt. The problem is not the appearance of `%`; the problem is that it's on the same line as your program's output. This is solved by outputting a line feed.

```c
printf( "Your number is: %d\n", thisNumber );
```

When you combined the two statements, you left out the `\n`.